# How to make ajax request on pagination in display tag?

Tags: ajax, jsp, pagination, displaytag

I'm using display tag pagination 1.2 in my jsp page to show logs of the application and filtering the data on the basis of its users, category and date. When data is filtered, an ajax call goes to controller and it replaces the current display table with another written in another jsp page with the filtered data. But, when I go to next page(of pagination, 1,2,3...) it loses all the filters applied and reloads the complete tab with all the data.
I tried implementing the solution mentioned in below link, but it didn't work.
http://www.jquery-plugins.info/display-tag-ajax-plugin-00012494.htm

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I was using a different method to get the filtered logs, now redirected the control to the similar method which is used to get the complete logs. And it works fine now :)